# how to fix Conflicting Jquery sources?

Tags: jquery

I have a page where i have a countdown and flow player. I have to include two different jquery sources. If i take out one the countdown clock doesn't work. If i take out the other the player doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery.noConflict(true);
        $(function () {
            var Day = new Date();
            Day = new Date(2015, 08, 02, 12, 12, 15, 00)
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: Day});
            $('#year').text(Day.getFullYear());
        });
        var videopath = "http://www.site.co.uk/Video/";
        var swfplayer = videopath + "videos/flowplayer-3.1.1.swf";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`jQuery.noConflict(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

If necessary, we can free up the jQuery name as well by passing true as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if we must do this (for example, if we need to use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page), we need to consider that most plug-ins rely on the presence of the jQuery variable and may not operate correctly in this situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript">       
        $(function () {
            var Day = new Date();
            Day = new Date(2015, 08, 02, 12, 12, 15, 00)
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: Day});
            $('#year').text(Day.getFullYear());
        });
   jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
        var videopath = "http://www.site.co.uk/Video/";
        var swfplayer = videopath + "videos/flowplayer-3.1.1.swf";
</script>
```

Comment: When i use jQuery.noConflict(true); flowplayer still does not work

Comment: @Beginner The problem is your plugins depend on the jQuery variable. So you tried to render your first plugin with the first source and after your first plugin include the second jquery source and then render the second plugin. So every plugin use its own source.

Comment: erm can you show how this would look i dont think i understand?

Comment: @Beginner Yeah your problem is that countdown depend on the jQuery variable - so you have to rewrite the countdown plugin to use your own jQuery variable - Or better use the newest flowPlayer